# React Native won't recognise import

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to import a component into another, but react native keeps throwing error of:

> [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module `./components/ColorBox` from `App.js`:

Below is an image describing my file structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of `colorBox`? Are you exporting it?

Answer (score 0):

Please export ColorBox component.

For example, in ColorBox.js

```
const ColorBox = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      ...
    <View>
  )
}

export default ColorBox;
```

Comment: ColorBox was already exported. Thank you, @nightbird8n. I totally deleted the file, and rewrote the component. For some reason, it worked.